# How to validate an image before saving in a file

Tags: php, image, file-handling

I have a function that saves the image in the respective folder.

I want to check if the image already exist in the folder , first with name if the name are same then with the SHA1 of the image

My current function looks something like this

```
function descargarImagen($id,$url,$pais1)
{


    $ruta = rutaBaseImagen($id,$_POST['pais']);

    $contenido = file_get_contents($url);

    $ext = explode('.', $url);
    $extension = $ext[count($ext) -1];

    $imagen['md5'] = md5($contenido);
    $imagen['sha1'] = sha1($contenido);
    $imagen['nombre'] = $imagen['md5'].'.'.$extension;

    $ficherof = $pais[$pais1]['ruta_imagenes'].'/'.$ruta.'/'.$imagen['nombre'];
    $ficherof = str_replace('//', '/', $ficherof);

//Here before putting the file I want to check if the image already exist in the folder


    file_put_contents($ficherof, $contenido);

    $s = getimagesize($ficherof);

    $imagen['mime'] = $s["mime"];
    $imagen['size'] = $s[0].'x'.$s[1];
    $imagen['url'] = $urlbase_imagenes.'/'.$ruta.'/'.$imagen['nombre'];
    $imagen['url'] = str_replace('//', '/', $imagen['url']);
    $imagen['date'] = time();
    $imagen['fichero'] = $ficherof;

    return $imagen;
}
```

I am trying to validate in two ways 
1.If the name of the image is present in the folder or not .
2.If present then check if the image is same or different , because there could be new image but same name

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So... where is the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: @rr-  i need to validate before doing this  `file_put_contents($ficherof, $contenido);` like what function I should use to check if it exsist in the given folder,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this,

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    //echo "Sorry, file already exists.";

    /** 
    * validate images that are different but have same name 
    * we can use base64_encode function to compare the old and new image 
    * basics: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php 
    * online conversion help: http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image
    */
    $base64_encoded_new_image=base64_encode(file_get_contents($name_of_your_new_image_that_you_want_to_upload));
    $base64_encoded_old_image=base64_encode(file_get_contents($name_of_the_image_that_already_exists));
    if ($base64_encoded_new_image!=$base64_encoded_old_image) {
        /** so the images are actually not same although they have same name 
        * now do some other stuffs
        */
    }
}
```

for more information please visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: any Idea how we can validate images that are different but have same name ?.

Comment: one last validation , If the file names are different but the file is same how to detect that

Answer (score 2):

The hint given by this comment:

```
//Here before putting the file I want to check if the image already exist in the folder
```

makes me think you're asking for [`file_exists`](https://php.net/manual/pl/function.file-exists.php), which is the first thing that's shown if you search for "php file exist" in any search engine...

Comment: and how I can match the SHA1 of the files, Like suppose the file is existing then it might be possible that different image witht he same name is being saved . So in that case what should i do ?

Comment: You can either choose to name the file with `$imageSha1 . '.png'`, or keep track of already uploaded hashes in the database (or, if you deal with <1000 images, in a simple text file). I'd go with naming them by their hashes instead of user input, unless you need direct access to the files. If you don't care about being slow, you could also use `glob()` to check if there are any files whose names contain a portion of a string.